# passing NSArray into tableview swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to connect my swift ios app to mysql with php... and the upon receiving the JSON from the php.. i converted it into nsarray and tried to populate my tableview with it.. however it doesnt seem to show anything in the tableview when i run it.... the data is successful in passing into the NSArray as i see my result when i print(values).. it just cant seem to show up on my tableview and i dont know why

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var values:NSArray = []

@IBAction func php(_ sender: Any) {
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://localhost/try.php")
    let data = NSData(contentsOf: url! as URL)
    values = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data! as Data, options:JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! NSArray
    print (values)
    tableView.reloadData()
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return values.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

    cell.descriptionView.text = (values[indexPath.row] as AnyObject) as? String



    return cell
}
```

Comment: Have you set the table view delegates?

Comment: You say that the values are `print`ing ok. What happens if you say `cell.descriptionView.text = "\(values[indexPath.row])"` ? Your double cast is pretty meaningless... `print` does not cast the values to `String`.

Comment: ... also, why use `NSArray`, `NSData` and `NSURL` rather than the Swift equivalents? - these are not your problem, but they are not making life any easier!

Comment: Is `values` an array of Strings? If not you won't see anything. By the way in Swift 3 do not use `NSURL`, `NSData`  and `NSArray`. And `mutableContainers` is completely useless in Swift

Comment: Have you set the `tableView.dataSource = self`?

Comment: @Grundwaldeatsacoelacanth yes i have set the delegate and data source

Comment: @vadian it isnt but doesnt this converts it? .. (values[indexPath.row] as AnyObject) as? String

Comment: Then check vadian's comment. If you  do let someString = (values[indexPath.row] as AnyObject) as? String  does someString have an value?

Comment: @Pierce yes i have and the data source as well

Comment: No, it does not. If it isn't a string you get `nil`

Comment: @Grimxn i was just following a tutorial.. im new to swift! however the tutorial was for swift 2.0 which is why like im stuck with this

Comment: Look for a better tutorial, Even loading data over the network with a synchronous method like `Data(contentsOf` is horrible :/

Comment: @Grundwaldeatsacoelacanth values itself has a value but i dont think that someString has a value since it doesnt print out anything when i run the app is there anyway around this?

Comment: sorry im new to all this which is why i just followed a tutorial... is there a way i can print out the values of nsarray into a text format? like into a textview or something?

Comment: `let strings:[String] = values.map({"\($0)"})` - but all this will do is the same as `print` - you really need to understand the *actual* structure of your data!

Comment: The question could have answered if you wouldn't keep the content of the array as a secret.

Comment: {
        description = "Assess, treat, and care for patients with breathing disorders. Assume primary responsibility for all respiratory care modalities, including the supervision of respiratory therapy technicians. Initiate and conduct therapeutic procedures; maintain patient records; and select, assemble, check, and operate equipment.";
        title = "Respiratory Therapists";
    }
@vadian this is the content of the array.. it has 5 of these description AND title

Comment: or is there a way i can just convert the NSData obtained into something else that can be printed out? @vadian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the recommended way to load data over the network.

As mentioned in the comment do not use `NSArray`, `NSData` and `NSURL` in Swift 3. `URLSession` loads the data asynchronously and in the background. The table view is reloaded on the main thread.

```
var values = [[String:String]]()

@IBAction func php(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let url = URL(string: "http://localhost/try.php")!
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
            return
        }
        do {
            self.values = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:[]) as! [[String:String]]
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    let item = values[indexPath.row]
    cell.descriptionView.text = item["title"]
    return cell
}
```

Comment: hi thank you for helping me with this... however it prompted a couple of errors.... like "ambiguous reference to member dataTask(with:completionHandler:) on this line... let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

Comment: and also "ambiguous reference to member subscript" on this line.. let item = values[indexPath.row]

your help is greatly appreciated mate!

Comment: Using exactly this code (no `NS` prefixed Foundation counterparts) you can't get `ambiguous reference` related to URLSession, Regarding the second error it's my bad,  it must be an array, I edited the answer.

Comment: urmm i have a question... the code and everything works perfectly on my ios simulator.. however when i port it over to the ipad... it doesnt work.. like after i pressed the button... it doesnt generate anything.. do you reckon you know why?

Comment: Is any data loaded at all?

Comment: nope its just blank as tho i didnt click the button at all

Comment: could it be due to my URL string?

Comment: Yes, you have to pass the IP-address or host name of the target Mac